# Ripple effect on Toolbar cut off

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar

I'm using a `Toolbar` in my app and am inflating it with a menu.
I have a issue here because the ripple effect is automatically added to the button but the left most button's ripple effect is cut off by the boundary of the menu area.
You can see the ripple expand but it is then but off on the left side.
Any idea how to remedy this issue?

[image]

Comment: can you post a screen shot a gif?

Comment: what are the bounds of the button. The ripple stays within the bound of the view. Can you check that??

Comment: You can have a unbounded ripple https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable.html

Comment: Check  gmail screen shot @ http://s29.postimg.org/hxbntdjh3/image.png. The view has a certain bound but ripple is unbounded

Comment: Well the thing is all I'm doing is inflating a menu to the toolbar. The menu items are defined in the menu xml file.

Comment: the ripple is there for your toolbar by default. I am not sure how you have the ripple cut only on side

Comment: I'm assuming it's because it's cut off by boundary of the area dedicated for inflated menu which doesn't take into account the ripple effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I came across this too, after playing around I found our custom `ThemeOverlay` had its background set.

Try removing `android:background` from your Toolbar style and theme.

See below I commented out: `<item name="android:background">@color/toolbar</item>`. It works as expected after that.

```
<style name="MyTheme.Overlay"
  parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
  <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/text_primary</item>
  <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/text_secondary</item>
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background</item>

  <!--<item name="android:background">@color/toolbar</item>-->

  <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
  <item name="colorPrimary">@color/toolbar</item>

  <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
  <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/toolbar</item>

  <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated,
     which is used to tint widgets -->
  <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

</style>
```

Comment: Removing a useless `android:background="@color/colorWhite"` from the `Toolbar` did the trick for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add button in toolbar like a simple view, for example:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"> 

<ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="ICON HERE"
        android:background="@null"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

> android:background="@null"

it will disable the ripple effect from the button

Comment: The problem here is that I'm adding those buttons by inflating a menu, not by adding them directly into the Toolbar's layout.