# Ripple Selector Cut Off At Parent Background

Tags: android, android-animation

When you use the background `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"` it gives a nice circle ripple background.  At https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html it says that `It will be drawn upon, and bounded by, the nearest parent of the view with a non-null background.`

How do you get around this?  I know there must be a way because while using the standard ActionBar, it worked fine.  When I used the compat Toolbar, it didn't work anymore and gets cut off.  If you take off the colored background from the toolbar it works fine, but I want a colored toolbar...Does anyone know how to use the Toolbar class and still have the rippled selector be unbounded?

As a note I am asking about this for the Toolbar, but I have a few other places where I also need to do the same thing (I use a pull up bar like Play Music has that needs have unbounded buttons as well).  So while a work-around for the Toolbar would be nice, it would be nice to have a generic solution as well.  Also note that I am NOT talking about the problem described in [Ripple effect on Toolbar cut off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31645886/ripple-effect-on-toolbar-cut-off).  I am talking about the selector being cutoff at the bounds of the parent, not cutoff at the button's bounds.