# Disable navigation icon riple effect in toolbar

Tags: android

Not sure what you call the round effect when you click to go back to previous activity in my case (arrow back icon) but i like to disable that.

This is the code that puts it on the toolbar, but i cant seem to find (if there is) an option to disable that round effect when clicked.

```
 mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
 setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back));
```

Like this round effect buttons produce in toolbar's when pressed. I presume a Material design effect.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

By changing in your theme you can achieve that. Remove `<item name="android:background">@color/toolbar</item>` from your theme defined in style.

Follow this [stack-overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31843499/2022000).

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/yourToolbarId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/yourId"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            app:layout_width="wrap_content"
            app:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:minHeight="?attr/actionBarHeight"
            app:minWidth="?attr/actionBarHeight"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

and getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false); in conjunction
and dont use this
mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back));

Also you have to manually set your click listener to perform specific action you need when it is pressed.

Comment: ok seems to doing something but i dont see the icon. let me post what ive done in my question

Answer (score -3):

Use false instead of true

```
  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

Comment: This is not what he is asking, he just wants to disable the ripple effect

Comment: @QAMAR yeah that's right that round (ripple) effect . Ill see if can find a pic and post it in the question